# MySQL trying to use current schema during WITH statement

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a problem shown below the commented line where I'm unable to use the "CTE" table (common table expression) while using a WITH statement.

```
CREATE VIEW `somthing.iii`.`vwCarSalesData` AS
WITH `listdates` ( weekdate ) AS (
            SELECT CONVERT(Now(3), DATE) AS DATE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Timestampadd(day,-7,weekdate)
            FROM   listdates
            WHERE  weekdate > DATE_ADD(CONVERT(sysdate(3), DATE), INTERVAL 13*-7 day)
)
SELECT     Sum(CASE WHEN closedate > weekdate AND createddate <= weekdate THEN 1                                  ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDeals,
           Sum(CASE WHEN closedate > weekdate AND createddate <= weekdate THEN Round(Ifnull(amount,0),0)          ELSE 0 END) AS PipelineValue,
           Sum(CASE WHEN closedate > weekdate AND createddate <= weekdate THEN Round(Ifnull(expectedrevenue,0),0) ELSE 0 END) AS ExpectedRevenue,
           c.id AS CategoryID, weekdate AS Added
FROM       `somthing.iii`.Ocars AS o
--error happens as this crossjoin, it is still trying to use the schema table named somthing.listdates
CROSS JOIN `listdates`
JOIN       `somthing.iii`.`Categories` AS c
ON         o.category = c.NAME
Where      isclosed != 1 
AND stagename != 'Cancelled' 
AND stagename != 'Closed Lost - N/A'
GROUP BY   weekdate,
           c.id
```

I have a schema named "somthing.iii" and it tries to use this schema to look for a table rather than using the tale listed in the "WITH" statement. I have tried removing ` character but this makes no difference.

Error Code: 1146. Table 'somthing.iii.listdates' doesn't exist

Comment: If your schema is named `somthing`, then why are you spelling it `somthing.iii`?

Comment: This was a mistake on my end. edited the question

Comment: Post the error message you've received.

Comment: Your CTE term is self referencing (recursive).  You need `WITH RECURSIVE listdates ...` to access `listdates` from within the same `WITH` clause term.  Without that, MySQL will attempt to resolve `listdates` from the current database.  It's not the `CROSS JOIN` causing this.  Maybe you're using MariaDB.  Show the result of `SELECT version();`  See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=de5754768ef1032df7d1972d7cdd4400

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB are slightly different here.  Check this too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64ce576b41f6b7adf0a781b46f079045  MySQL handles the self referencing case (by ignoring it) when the term is not actually used.  MariaDB will not ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=323eda8d4771b55598f8d2f73c075d15)

MySQL requires a self referencing recursive `WITH` clause term to use the `RECURSIVE` keyword (with one exception, shown in the fiddle), like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (lev) AS (
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL
       SELECT lev+1 FROM cte WHERE lev < 6
     )
SELECT * FROM cte
;
```

Without that keyword, the reference to that `cte` identifier is resolved by objects stored in the database.  If the object is not found, we see this `doesn't exist` error.

MySQL has one exception to this.  If that self referencing CTE term is not used in the subsequent query expressions, the unresolved self reference is not detected and no error is seen, as shown in the fiddle.

Here's the example:

```
WITH listdates ( weekdate ) AS (
            SELECT CONVERT(Now(3), DATE) AS DATE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Timestampadd(day,-7,weekdate)
            FROM   listdates
            WHERE  weekdate > DATE_ADD(CONVERT(sysdate(3), DATE), INTERVAL 13*-7 day)
)
SELECT 123 FROM dual
;
```

No error is detected here, by MySQL.  MariaDB does detect this as an error, however.

**In the original question**, it wasn't the `CROSS JOIN listdates` causing the error, it was the reference to `listdates` within the `listdates` common table expression.

**Change the following:**

```
WITH `listdates` ( weekdate ) AS (
```

**to:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE `listdates` ( weekdate ) AS (
```